# C++ static Allocation with parameterized constructor

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

I want to use compile time allocation (static allocation) to allocate an object of a class through its parameterized constructor. The parameters which are passed are compile time constants which leads me to believe that this should be possible.

For example, consider the code shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

class myclass
{
        private:
                std::vector<uint32_t> myvec;
        public:
                myclass(uint32_t num_elem)
                {
                        myvec.resize(num_elem);
                }

                void print_vec()
                {
                        for(int i: this->myvec)
                                std::cout << i << std::endl;
                }
};

int main()
{
        myclass* obj = new myclass(10);
        (*obj).print_vec();
        delete obj;
        return 0;
}
```

This code performs dynamic allocation when it allocates `obj`. To convert this to static allocation, I rewrote it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

class myclass
{
        private:
                std::vector<uint32_t> myvec;
        public:
                myclass(uint32_t num_elem)
                {
                        myvec.resize(num_elem);
                }

                constexpr void print_vec()
                {
                        for(int i: this->myvec)
                                std::cout << i << std::endl;
                }
};

int main()
{
        constexpr myclass obj(10);
        obj.print_vec();
        return 0;
}
```

Note that since I also made `print_vec` a `constexpr` function, what I expected was that the compiled binary would just have a single print which prints ten 0s in a row. However, when I tried to compile this code using `g++ --std=c++20 test2.cpp`, I got the following errors:

```
test2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test2.cpp:24:27: error: the type ‘const myclass’ of ‘constexpr’ variable ‘obj’ is not literal
   24 |         constexpr myclass obj(10);
      |                           ^~~
test2.cpp:5:7: note: ‘myclass’ is not literal because:
    5 | class myclass
      |       ^~~~~~~
test2.cpp:5:7: note:   ‘myclass’ is not an aggregate, does not have a trivial default constructor, and has no ‘constexpr’ constructor that is not a copy or move constructor
test2.cpp:25:22: error: passing ‘const myclass’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   25 |         obj.print_vec();
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
test2.cpp:15:32: note:   in call to ‘constexpr void myclass::print_vec()’
   15 |                 constexpr void print_vec()
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~
```

I don't fully know how to use `constexpr` yet so I don't know what I've done wrong. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: This will not work as shown, since the `std::vector` can't be allocated at compile-time, only at runtime. Making `obj` be `constexpr` doesn't change that.  C++20 does add the ability to create a true `constexpr vector` (see [P1004R2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1004r2.pdf)), but only a few compilers implement that feature yet (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20)

Comment: The problem is that [constexpr allocation support in C++20 is limited - you can only have transient allocation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69498591/12002570). This means that you can't have `int main(){constexpr std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};}` but can have `constexpr int f(){std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3}; return v.size();}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that [constexpr allocation support in C++20 is limited - you can only have transient allocation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69498591/12002570) Basically this means that you can't have `int main(){constexpr std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};}` but can have `constexpr int f(){std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3}; return v.size();}`

---

Since you want static allocation, `std::array` would be a perfect choice. You can make `myclass` a class template having a `std::array` member as shown below. Also do note that `std::array`'s size must be a compile time constant(which must be supplied at the time of its construction) while `std::vector` can be resized at will.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
template<std::size_t N>
class myclass
{
        private:  
                std::array<uint32_t, N> myvec;
        public:
                
                constexpr myclass(): myvec() 
                {
                        
                }

                constexpr void print_vec() const   
                {
                        for(int i: myvec)
                                std::cout << i << std::endl;
                }
};

int main()
{
        constexpr  myclass<32> obj;  
        obj.print_vec();
        return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5Y4sYrxPP)

Comment: @Sebastian Done.

Comment: Hopefully, `std::array<T, 0>` is legal, else `print_vec` would be UB (pre-C++23) as "it should exists at least one set of argument values such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression". :)

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, this question states [std::array is required by the standard to be well-defined even when the size is zero, so that `std::array<T, 0>` is well-defined even though `int[0]` is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265947/does-the-standard-require-that-stdarrayt-0-behave-like-it-does-not-have-tra). Though the comments there seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Jarod42 Also [Is there a reason for zero sized std::array in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152435/is-there-a-reason-for-zero-sized-stdarray-in-c11)

Comment: My point is `constexpr` with **nearly** unconditional call to `std::cout` (which is not `constexpr`).

Comment: Perhaps `print_vec` should not be`constexpr` itself due to `std::cout` and there should be another (`constexpr`) function it is calling concatenating the output into a single string-like result, which is then printed with one`cout` in `print_vec`. The OP asked for, why the `cout`s are not combined into one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered this?

```
template<size_t N>
class myclass
{
  private:
    uint32_t myvec[N] = {};   // initialize with zeroes.

  public:
      void print_vec() const
      {
         for (auto i: myvec)
             std::cout << i << std::endl;
      }
};

int main() 
{
    constexpr auto obj = myclass<32>{};
    obj.print_vec();
    return 0;
}
```

As an aside, operations on std::cout cannot be executed at compile-time, for rather obvious reasons.